# How to get hydrogen indices in RDKit substructure matches

Tags: cheminformatics

I am searching for functional groups in RDKit molecules and want to get the corresponding atom indices. Using `GetSubstructMatches()` however does not return some (implicit?) hydrogen indices.
My code is

```
from rdkit import Chem

patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts("[CH3;X4]")
patt = Chem.AddHs(patt, explicitOnly=True)

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("CC(=O)Br")
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)

match_indices = mol.GetSubstructMatches(patt)
```

This only returns the index of the carbon atom. How could I get the hydrogen indices as well?

Comment: I think the problem is that your SMARTS doesn't actually indicate the hydrogen atoms. What I read is "an aliphatic carbon with 3 hydrogen atoms and 4 total connections" (i.e., only the carbon atom matters). If you want the hydrogen too, you need something like `[CH3][#1][#1][#1]`

Comment: You might find this answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128740/5017 and https://smarts.plus/smartsview useful for testing SMARTS patterns.